# How to play insane Beast online

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I want to play Beast online with 4 others on insane but every time I try to play the difficulty is always set to normal.  I have already beat it on normal and want to move on.  Is there a way to set my difficulty level when playing online?

I just want to play with 4 others online that are not on my friends list.  So I can join a match or host one.  But I have not been able to figure out how to get the difficulty to be set above normal.

Comment: Add some more detail; what kind of online match is it? Are you hosting?

Comment: @Dustin - I added some more detail.  I just am not sure how to do it.  I don't mind hosting the match or joining one.  Whatever works.

Comment: The only way I've been able to do this is by getting a party together and creating a private match.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to play Beastmode on a higher difficulty is to open a lobby and invite players to a private game.